# WPF canvas render

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this canvas and some objects (images, paths) that I want to move every millisecond with 1px to left. After I did this, I noticed a lot of lag. How can I improve the rendering performance?

```
    <Grid>    
        <Canvas Grid.Row="0">
            <Image x:Name="Cover" Source="happy_footer.png" Stretch="Uniform" Canvas.Bottom="0" Canvas.Left="0" Width="2500"/>
            <Image x:Name="rocketMan" Source="rocketman.gif" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="50,300,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
            <Path x:Name="rocketManPath" Stroke="Green" Fill="#4CFF0000" Data="M 5,400 L 15,305 L 80,295 L 50,400 Z" Canvas.Left="40" />
            <Path x:Name="Building1" Stroke="Green" Fill="#4CFF0000" Data="M 365,518 L 365,425 L 655,425 L 655,518 Z" />
            <Path x:Name="Building2" Stroke="Green" Fill="#4CFF0000" Data="M 735,528 L 735,248 L 778,218 L 925,218 L 925,528 Z" />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

**Edit:** My image is generated, so every few milliseconds I'll add another shape at the end. I'll never stop.

Comment: Of course this depends on _how you did this_. The most performant way to my knowledge in WPF is to use `RenderTransform`.

Comment: WPF is not really a great platform for game development. In any case, the way you described this in your comments to Mike is not the correct way to do something like this. Of course you lag if you're moving an infinitely increasing number of items. You should work on cleaning up objects that aren't visible or reusing objects instead of creating new ones all the time.

Comment: Do you have a reason to move every 1 ms or was that an arbitrary choice?  Fluid animation is usually considered to be 60 frames per second, or once every 16.667 ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know where your `Canvas` should stop you can try `DoubleAnimation` [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you don't know where you have to stop, you can still use it and start Animation every few hundred milliseconds with a new start and stop

Comment: My image will be generated, so every few milliseconds I'll add another shape at the end. I'll never stop.

Comment: So you add another `Image` to your WDF and move all the other ones 1 px to the left. So you have one big `Image` consist of a lot of Images. What are you trying to do? Maybe there is a better way. Think about a Game Engine.

Comment: I have small images with buildings and I want to build a city. I want also to move the scene every few milliseconds. Any ideas?

Comment: wpf is not made for this. Try a Game Engine for example Unity3D

Comment: Everything it's in *2D*. I'm stuck with WPF, can't change it.

Comment: There are also Game Engines for 2D Games even Unity (Unity2D). You can also use c# so if you distracted your logic from your ViewModel it should not that much work.
I'm not sure if wpf can handle a lot of `Images`. But you could use some techniques from Game engeneering. For example tiling or you use a huge background images wich moves but the player don't sees it completle. This should fix your moving background problem.

Comment: Well this game will be using kinect for windows, and I already build some of the gestures. Not sure if it'll work with Unity

Comment: I go offline for today but if you want i can give you some tips tommorow.

Comment: I found out Unity supports Kinect. But i also came up with this approach. You could make bigger Images. It then is a bit out of your View but i think you can hide it good enough. Now you don't have this much images. Also you can reuse Images as your Buildings and don't forget to remove the ones which go out of your window.